# How to send custom Bluetooth commands to a ST17H26 with Swift iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am trying to connect to a device(SP107E using an ST17H26 LE Bluetooth IC) that takes in audio through a speaker and makes the attached LED light strip react to the music. I am making a beta piece of software to connect to the light-strip and override this functionality and make my own music reactions piggybacking off of their hardware.

I have made my iOS Swift app discover the SP107E and connect with it. Once it connects with the device it discovers the services and the peripheral's characteristics. [image: Console Output]

This is the code which discovers the characteristics for the peripheral. Upon discovering the different characteristics it outputs it to the console as seen in the image above.

```swift
    func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverCharacteristicsFor service: CBService, error: Error?) {
        guard let characteristics = service.characteristics else {return}

        for characteristic in characteristics {
            print(characteristic)
            print("Properties \(characteristic.uuid): \(characteristic.properties) ")

            if(characteristic.properties.contains(.read)){
                print("\(characteristic.uuid): properties contains .read")
                peripheral.readValue(for: characteristic)
            }
            if(characteristic.properties.contains(.notify)){
                print("\(characteristic.uuid): properties contains .notify")
                peripheral.setNotifyValue(true, for: characteristic)
            }
        }
    }
```

Now I want to send data to the SP107E; however, this characteristic is not documented by Bluetooth with the `UUID` of `FFE1` or `FFE2`. I want to be able to send data to the device and change the way the LED lights up from the music. The company has created an app to pair with their device using LE Bluetooth but it is outdated and does not want to do what I need it to do. How should I go about using these services and send data to the SP107E?

Comment: You either need to find some documentatio,  use some sort of Bluetooth sniffer to reverse engineer or discover through trial and error the values that need to be written to those characteristics.

Comment: @Paulw11 I have been using a Bluetooth sniffer to try to reverse engineering a solution to this and I haven't gotten anywhere. Most of the packets sent are just broadcasting not actual data transmission.